# OxyPlot.Axes.DateTimeAxis on x axes shifts the hours instead of starting at data contained in IO.Swagger.Model.DataPoint.X value

Tags: oxyplot

I am using *Xamarin.Forms* for mobile app, the version of OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms is 1.1.0-unstable0011 with OxyPlot.Core 2.0.0-unstable1013.

Here is the data:

```
"points": [
                {
                    "x": "10/19/2020 7:00 AM",
                    "y": "NaN"
                },
                {
                    "x": "10/19/2020 7:15 AM",
                    "y": "NaN"
                },
                {
                    "x": "10/19/2020 7:30 AM",
                    "y": "NaN"
                },
                {
                    "x": "10/19/2020 7:45 AM",
                    "y": "NaN"
                },
                {
                    "x": "10/19/2020 8:00 AM",
                    "y": "NaN"
                },
                {
                    "x": "10/19/2020 8:15 AM",
                    "y": "NaN"
                },
                {
                    "x": "10/19/2020 8:30 AM",
                    "y": "NaN"
                },
                {
                    "x": "10/19/2020 8:45 AM",
                    "y": "NaN"
                },
                {
                    "x": "10/19/2020 9:00 AM",
                    "y": "NaN"
                },
                {
                    "x": "10/19/2020 9:15 AM",
                    "y": "NaN"
                },
                {
                    "x": "10/19/2020 9:30 AM",
                    "y": "NaN"
                },
                {
                    "x": "10/19/2020 9:45 AM",
                    "y": "NaN"
                },
                {
                    "x": "10/19/2020 10:00 AM",
                    "y": "NaN"
                },
                {
                    "x": "10/19/2020 10:15 AM",
                    "y": "NaN"
                },
                {
                    "x": "10/19/2020 10:30 AM",
                    "y": "NaN"
                },
                {
                    "x": "10/19/2020 10:45 AM",
                    "y": "NaN"
                },
                {
                    "x": "10/19/2020 11:00 AM",
                    "y": "NaN"
                },
                {
                    "x": "10/19/2020 11:15 AM",
                    "y": "NaN"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Instead of starting at specified time, time shifted as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem, wrong index was used.